# Using data from column in DataFrame to pass as string variable via API

Tags: python, pandas, api

I am trying to use data from a column in a Pandas DataFrame as a variable in an API call.  I can't figure out how to convert the data into the correct formatting to pass it to the API.

For context, I am grabbing ProductIDs (i.e. the APIs unique DB reference for a product) from one call to grab meta data about said products in another call.  Just calling the whole DB is not an option as I generally have 100s of ProductIDs whereas the DB is 140'000 deep so this would be very inefficient!  I've managed to achieve what I want to do via GoogleAppsScript / JavaScript but looking to migrate to Python to make the whole job more efficient.

I call:

```
prodIDs = table['PRODUCT_ID']
```

which returns:

```
185    115711.0
186    115859.0
187     96392.0
188    128546.0
189         NaN
Name: PRODUCT_ID, Length: 760, dtype: float64
```

I then pass it to the API with:

```
meta = Erply.getProducts(recordsOnPage='1000', productIDs=prodIDs)
```

but the response comes back blank.  The API is not reading any of the ProductIDs.  When I do it manually, such as:

```
meta = Erply.getProducts(recordsOnPage='1000', productIDs='128546, 128546')
```

then it works a treat!

So, I figure that I need to convert the "prodIDs" in someway so that they can be passed over the API.

The API says:

productIDs  Retrieve specific products. Multiple product IDs, separated by commas, such as: 1,2,3,4,5   String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.str.cat()` to concatenate and specify a newline:

```
>>> prodIDs = pd.Series([115711, 115859, 96393], dtype=np.float64)

>>> prodIDs.astype(int).astype(str).str.cat(sep=', ')
'115711, 115859, 96393'
```

Your question implies you want a string of `int`s.  If you want floats, just drop `.astype(int)`:

```
>>> prodIDs.astype(str).str.cat(sep=', ')
'115711.0, 115859.0, 96393.0'
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#concatenation

Regarding your commment:

> I think I just need to drop the NaN from the range. What's the best way to achieve that? "ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

One way would be to use `numpy.isfinite()` as a filter.

```
>>> prodIDs = pd.Series([115711, 115859, 96393, np.inf], dtype=np.float64)

>>> prodIDs[np.isfinite(prodIDs)]
0    115711.0
1    115859.0
2     96393.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Excellent.  That's nearly done the trick.  I think I just need to drop the NaN from the range.  What's the best way to achieve that?

"ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for great feedback Brad.
All solved now with a couple of lines:

```
prodIDs = pd.Series(table['PRODUCT_ID'], dtype=np.float64)
prodIDs = prodIDs.dropna().astype(int).astype(str).str.cat(sep=', ')
meta = Erply.getProducts(recordsOnPage='1000', productIDs=prodIDs)
```

Now I'm getting the meta data only on the items I need making the application much more efficient.  Thanks for helping a Python Beginner : )

Comment: You can also say `table['PRODUCT_ID'].astype(float)`